# HTML::image align text

Tags: html, css, laravel

Sorry for the stupid question but I'm fairly new to Laravel and couldn't find a specific example nor such for this. Is it possible to align the text in an image put like this?:

```
{{ HTML::image('img/site/news/' . $article->NEWS_ID . '/md-' . $article->media[0]->FILE_NAME, '', ['class' => 'article-thumb']) }}
```

I tried putting it like the following but it just blew the page:

```
{{ HTML::image('img/site/news/' . $article->NEWS_ID . '/md-' . $article->media[0]->FILE_NAME, '', [array('class' => 'article-thumb', 'class' => 'text-center')]) }}
```

Then I tried like the following but there was no change, the FILE_NAME I wanted to get in the center of the image still remained aligned to the left

```
{{ HTML::image('img/site/news/' . $article->NEWS_ID . '/md-' . $article->media[0]->FILE_NAME, '', array('class' => 'article-thumb text-center')) }}
```

Comment: try `.article-thumb{text-align:center;}` in your css, note the dot before it

Comment: text-center works if you have http://getbootstrap.com on. Unless you do, just add css declaration like `.article-thumb{text-align:center}` to you css